# cannot run shellinabox through a php api on centos

Tags: centos6.5

I want to start shellinabox on centos through a php api.

When the user hits the api, `shellinaboxd -p 'portno'` command should get executed and shellinabox should start on the particular port number.

But this does not happen, instead this error comes
Error :

> Failed to find any available port  [on tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log]
>   The code below runs correctly on ubuntu but not on centos.
>   Consider rest all things working fine.

```
$app->get('/test', function() {
    exec('shellinaboxd -p '.$port);
});
```

Executing:

`shellinaboxd -p 'someport'` on bash also works fine.

I have php5.5 and apache2 installed on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come out with a solution. Centos is SELINUX(Secured linux). So it does not allow any logging action from a process, like php api(in my case, whose user is apache) in its default mode that is "enforcing".

So change the SELINUX mode as:

'SELINUX=disabled' in   /etc/selinux/config

and reboot.

It has one more mode i.e. permissive.
Read more about it here: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Answer (score 1):

Error message `Failed to find any available port` tells you that port is already used.

Try different port.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the case, I am generating different port numbers and trying to run shellianbox on those ports. $port variable stores these generated ports (one at a time). These generated ports are free ports(range 4500-4600). I have checked if any service is running on the port generated.